# Inner Interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

I'm pretty new to Java and I don't understand what is this structure. I know what is an interface and how is defined, but in this case, I really don't know. Could you tell what is about?

```
public interface WebConstants {
    public interface Framework {
        String ACTION = "action";
    }

    public interface Look {
        String LIST_CONT = "list.cont";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every field inside an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. In this case `WebConstants` declares an inner interface (public, static, and final) `Framework` and (public, static, and final) `Look` which have also some (public, static, and final) String fields.

This is a (not very common) way to order constants in your code, with this structure you could type:

```
String action = WebConstants.Framework.ACTION;

String list = WebConstants.Look.LIST_CONT;
```

The advantage of this is that since the `WebConstants` is an interface you can't accidentally instanciate it

Comment: You can't prohibit client classes from "implementing" a constant interface, which is very bad practice as it makes a compile-time utility (accessing the constants without prefixing them) part of the client's external interface. Classes, on the other hand, can be made uninstantiable (with private constructors that unconditionally `throw new AssertionError()` or something like it), and are therefore better alternatives to put constants in than interfaces. With `import static` there's no reason at all to use constant interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into enums if you're looking at using a similar solution:

```
public enum WebConstants
{
    ACTION("action"), LIST_COUNT("list.count");

    private String display;

    private WebConstants(String display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public String getDisplay()
    {
        return display;
    }
}
```

So you could use it calling WebConstants.ACTION.getDisplay().

Having an interface of constants doesn't really make any sense to me.  A better way of doing things might be to have abstract accessor methods.

```
public interface ActionAware
{
    public String getAction();
}

public interface ListCountAware
{
    public String getListCount();
}

public abstract class AbstractUseCase implements ActionAware, ListCountAware
{

    public void doSomething()
    {
        String action = getAction();
        String listCount = getListCount();
    }

}

public final class SpecificUseCase extends AbstractUseCase
{
     public final static String ACTION = "specific.action";
     public final static String LIST_COUNT = "specific.list.count";

     public String getListCount()
     {
         return LIST_COUNT;
     }

     public String getAction()
     {
         return ACTION;
     }

     // other methods

}
```